# What are the arrows in my siddur?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, baal-teshuva

Shalom,

I'm a baal teshuva who recently began reciting daily prayers. I own several Koren siddurim and I notice in all of them, occasional small arrows pointing at the text. Does anyone know what these arrows indicate? I know downward pointing arrows indicate when we're supposed to bow, but I'm not sure about the ones pointing inward at the text.

Answer (score 8):

The explanation is shown in the *Guide to the Reader* section at the beginning of the siddur.

> A small arrow indicates the suggested starting point for the *Shaliach Tzibbur*. However, where the local custom differs, the *Shaliach Tzibbur* should certainly follow that custom

"*Shaliach Tzibbur*" means the one leading the communal service.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Koren uses two similar side-pointing arrows. The vast majority show where the *Shaliach Tzibbur* starts his short recitation, but there are also cases where the alternate arrow is used to show where he ends his section, usually in cases where the stopping point is not the obvious end of verse.

Comment: That was not mentioned in the *Guide to the Reader Section*

Comment: I don't have a Koren at home to check, but I clearly remember it, either in Kedushah d'Yotzer or Vayivarech David.

Comment: @Mike I have a Koren to check but am not sure exactly where you are pointing. I do see in Kedushah of Shmonah Esrai arrows pointing up to show where one rises on toes.